# PHP Query + IF ELSE

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I Have a PHP file doing a query

```
function getFiles()
{
    $solnid = $_GET[id];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM library WHERE libr_solutionId = '$solnid' AND libr_deleted IS NULL") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        echo "<br>No Related Links";
    } else {
        while($library = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<span style=\"margin-bottom: 5px;\"><a href=\"Solutions/image/".$library[libr_solutionref]."/".$library[libr_filename]."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"images/icon-download-02.png\" align=\"absmiddle\" style=\"margin-right: 5px;\"><span>".$library[libr_c_title]."</span></a></span><br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }       
}
```

I have tested the query in PHPMyAdmin and I get a result however when running the function in my page it only displays the 'No Related Links' statement any ideas anyone?

Comment: first you have a big fat SQL injection in your script.

Comment: I know but it's a closed system so that's not to much of an issue

Comment: Can you please post the output of `var_dump($solnid);`?

Comment: have you tried mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ???

Comment: closed system: 80% of attacks comes from collaborators plus it's a bad habit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the fixed code. :) The problem was that you used mysql_query on a Resource (the first mysql_query), and that will give 0 rows, or an exception..

```
function getFiles()
{
    $solnid = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM library WHERE libr_solutionId = '$solnid' AND libr_deleted IS NULL") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        echo "<br>No Related Links";
    } else {
        while($library = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<span style=\"margin-bottom: 5px;\"><a href=\"Solutions/image/".$library['libr_solutionref']."/".$library['libr_filename']."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"images/icon-download-02.png\" align=\"absmiddle\" style=\"margin-right: 5px;\"><span>".$library['libr_c_title']."</span></a></span><br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: You should also sanitize the parameter for `$solnid`, it is possible to exploit that SQL as it is right now and do some injects. :)

Comment: Nice catch! I totally missed the double mysql_query when I read through it.

Answer (score 0):

change your function to (change to lines)

```
function getFiles()
{
    $solnid = $_GET[id];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM library WHERE libr_solutionId = '$solnid' AND libr_deleted IS NULL") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        echo "<br>No Related Links";
    } else {
        while($library = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<span style=\"margin-bottom: 5px;\"><a href=\"Solutions/image/".$library[libr_solutionref]."/".$library[libr_filename]."\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"images/icon-download-02.png\" align=\"absmiddle\" style=\"margin-right: 5px;\"><span>".$library[libr_c_title]."</span></a></span><br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }       
}
```